# How to do a URL rewrite in iis from a 2nd level domain to a 3rd level domain

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

would like to forward all traffic from abc.xyz.com to go to abc.123.xyz.com

for example:
www.     abc.      xyz.   com => www.    abc.       123.      xyz.com

How can I do this with URL rewrite rules in iis?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use redirect directly:

```
<rule name="test1" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^www.abc.xyz.com$" />
     <action type="Redirect" url="www.abc.123.xyz.com" />
</rule>
```